# Why would rowGetter be called with argument of -1?

Tags: react-data-grid

I sometimes see rowGetter called with an argument of -1. Why would that happen? rowsCount is >0. This is a typical React/Redux app, debugging in vscode. How can I get it to use a non-minified version of react-data-grid so that I have some hope of tracking this down?